# Install Rtools 4.0 in Conda environment

Tags: r, conda, rtools

Recently I have been creating a R environment with Conda. I can install R 4.0 in an environment, but I cannot install Rtools 4.0. I have not seen a Anaconda Cloud channel with Rtools 4.0. For the moment I  have just found Rtools 3.4 (https://anaconda.org/r/rtools), but this version is not compatible with R 4.0. Anyone has an option to install Rtools 4.0?